# Is there a FAQ or centralized forum/group/list for the Kingkiller Chronicles?

Tags: patrick-rothfuss, the-kingkiller-chronicle

In high school I was really into the Wheel of Time series, which had a lovely usenet newsgroup and well-maintained FAQ to help centralize discussion of the mysteries in the series.  Does anybody know if something like this exists for Patrick Rothfuss' Kingkiller Chronicles?

I've seen some discussion in Song of Ice and Fire forums and on blogs like this: http://www.tor.com/blogs/2012/05/rothfuss-reread-pat-answers-the-admissions-questions

But nothing as clear as what I remember from the Wheel of Time FAQ 15 years ago.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a lot of activity around newer books on the older style discussion boards.  There's not even an active wiki (that I can find) on the Kingkiller Chronicles.  The most active discussion I've seen around these books is on the [KingkillerChronicle](http://www.reddit.com/r/KingkillerChronicle/) subreddit.

> This reddit is dedicated to discussion and links related to The Kingkiller Chronicle, a fantasy trilogy by Patrick Rothfuss, telling the biography of "Kvothe", an adventurer, arcanist and famous musician.

There's also a page for [The Kingkiller Chronicles](http://www.facebook.com/KingkillerChronicles) on Facebook, but it doesn't seem to be as active as reddit.

Comment: The subreddit seems pretty decent, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a SUPER late answer but I have recently launched the Fan Forums for the kingkiller chronicles books. You can find them at http://www.kkc.boards.net

Comment: Very recently - but hey, it's already got 59 members! www.kkc.boards.net! FTW!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Jo Walton's (A Hugo-winning novelist in her own right) [detailed re-read of the Kingkiller Chronicles](http://www.tor.com/features/series/patrick-rothfuss-reread) on Tor.com, and especially the comments.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly an old-school discussion board. Tvtropes.org has sites and disucssions to most stories (book/series/films) and is a good starting point to dive deeper into fictional material!

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheKingkillerChronicle